# ES6 '...' notation gives error in jslint?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs, jslint, jsx

I get `Unexpected token` error whenever I run the code against jslint while using '...' notation. I am using grommet-toolbox for Grommet UI (and UI/UX framework for React) and so when I run `gulp dev` command I get this error, thereby not being able write code like below:

`return {...state, fetching: true}`

(The above code is in line 10 of this file: https://github.com/learncodeacademy/react-js-tutorials/blob/master/5-redux-react/src/js/reducers/tweetsReducer.js)

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's not ES6/2015 and not ES2016 but not standardised syntax. You must use `babel-eslint` for it to work.

Answer (score 7):

The `Object spread operator` is not a ECMASCRIPT STANDARD, while `Array spread operator` is. So, probably this is the reason of your lint-issue.

You can find further information here: https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread

---

Just a note, I suggest you to have a look at [`eslint`](http://eslint.org/) because is the common linter used for esnext (it is pluggable and maybe has a solution to avoid this issue).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using spread operator, please try to use `Object.assign`, they ought to accomplish  the same thing. Just without jshint outputting warnings/errors.